# Facebook Link Sharing Issue

Tags: django, facebook, ssl, ssl-certificate, social-networking

I have a single "share to facebook" link on my site using Django Social Share. The issue is that the link being posted to Facebook isn't being scraped - the image, the description, and the title are not populating. All OG meta tags are present and correct, so I checked the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and it shows the following error:

```
SSL Error
Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.
Curl Error
Curl error: 60 (SSL_CACERT)
```

The site's SSL cert is perfectly valid - no errors or warnings at all. I'm using LetsEncrypt on Apache with a Django app behind it through WSGI. No issues with any other social networks.

An example of one of the links giving this error:
https://www.netizen.net/news/post/2643/netizen-ranks-184-on-the-2020-inc-5000-list

As you can see if you visit the page, there are no SSL errors. The same link is scraped just as expected on LinkedIn, Twitter, and elsewhere but FB seems to have this issue.

Comment: Google “ssl check”, input your host name into the first couple of results, check what they have to say.

Comment: No issues found. Tried three different checkers. Like I mentioned, only Facebook has this issue - it works fine on all other social sites.

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.netizen.net: _“The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate.”_

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.netizen.net&hideResults=on&latest: _“Chain issues: Incomplete”_

Comment: https://www.digicert.com/help/: _“TLS Certificate is not trusted - The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store). If you bought the certificate from a trusted authority, you probably just need to install one or more Intermediate certificates.”_

Comment: You seem to be lacking an intermediate certificate. Since Let’s Encrypt is used here, common web browsers might have the necessary certificates in their own storage already, but not everyone else on the web might (like Facebook.)

Comment: I kind of figured that might be the case. I'm using Let's Encrypt - standard configuration and management with certbot, nothing special. Is there a Let's Encrypt intermediate or bundle cert out there I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after going back in forth in the comments I found the solution based on guidance from [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe). In short, Let's Encrypt doesn't automatically include the `SSLCertificateChainFile` in the "standard" Apache configuration it performs, so it needs to be added manually. Once I did that, the links started sharing as expected on Facebook.

However, it only seemed to work properly using the `chain.pem` file as the chain file and NOT the `fullchain.pem` which includes extraneous certificate(s). Once I configured Apache as below, rebooted Apache, and ran the SSL check, it started working:

```
...
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/chain.pem
...
```

Now, the SSL certificate passes ALL checks and has an "A" rating and is trusted in all devices/platforms because the correct chain file is included:

[image]